# VS2015 Update model from database - unexpected exception

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with a lot of project.
Few of them are using EDMX.
It looks like I did something that crashed my EDMX files.
When I open EDMX and click option "Update Model from Database" I get a exception popup windows with message:
"An unexpected exception has occurred. The exception message is: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation.'."

[image: http://1drv.ms/20C9Vv0]

And interesting is it doesn't matter which project. Any EDMX in the solution give me this bug. I have VS 2015 with latest EF 6.1.3.

Please help me :)

Comment: do you see any details in the output window? if not, attach Windbg to the devenv.exe and look which exception Windbg catches and run **!analyze -v** in windbg to see more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

not sure if any one else is still having this issue. But I found a possible solution.

Open  View > Server Explorer. then open the 'data connections' node and delete any connections in there.

This seemed to have fixed it for me.

I ran windbg.exe as well and found it was throwing an exception in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler

Hope this helps

Comment: FYI: Today this is still the solution for VS 2015 Enterprise Update 3.